# possible way to block NoRedirect

Tags: php, redirect

is there any possible way to block or reject the NoRedirect from redirecting your site to index?

because I have this php code checking if the user is logged in

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

but the problem is, if the hacker blocked the redirect link of my site then he/she can access the pages even he/she didn't login to the site.

Any possible way to prevent this?

Comment: i have a page dashboard.php but if the hacker didn't login the website he/she can visit the dashboard.php by installing the noredirect plugin in the browser and putting the website link in the browser plugin named NoRedirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can end execution of your php code after sending the Location header. For example:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}
```

If the hacker blocks the redirect then he will see a blank page.